# request data, pass it to another component and return it in react

Tags: reactjs, components, axios

I want to display search results on a page. My idea was to make a submit that sends a request to the server. After receiving the data I iterate through it and call a function to process it in another component which should render processed data back to the parent component. Unfortunately no data rendered in the search component and no errors were given to debug.

**The main problem right now is that no data is returned from SearchResults; also I'm not sure if the data is received in that component.**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import SearchResults from "./SearchResults";

export default class SearchComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      query: "",
      searchresults: []
    };
  }

  submitSearchResults(searchresults) {
    return this.state.searchresults.map(function(object, i) {
      return <SearchResults obj={object} key={i} />;
    });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4200/serverport/spotify/" + this.state.song)
      .then(res => {
        const searchresults = res.data;

        for (var key in searchresults) {
          if (searchresults.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < searchresults[key].items.length; i++) {
              this.submitSearchResults(searchresults[key].items[i]);
            }
          }
        }
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.query}
            onChange={this.onChangeSong}
          />
          <input value="search" type="submit" />
        </form>
        <div>{this.submitSearchResults()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code that requests the data from server. I removed some irrelevant code to make it more readable.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

class SearchResults extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>works</div>;
  }
}

export default SearchResults;
```

This is the file where the data is supposed to be processed. I only render "works" for debugging.

Comment: I can't test it since I can't query the API endpoint but do not use this logic. Make your fetch query then set you state there. After that using your state map your other component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling the function that renders your search result JSX when the request is complete, you can set the `searchresults` in the state and the component will re-render automatically.

**Example**

```js
const axios = {
  get: () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({ data: [{ text: "foo" }, { text: "bar" }] });
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
};

class SearchComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    song: "",
    searchresults: []
  };

  submitSearchResults(searchresults) {
    return this.state.searchresults.map(function(object, i) {
      return <SearchResults obj={object} key={i} />;
    });
  }

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4200/serverport/spotify/" + this.state.song)
      .then(res => {
        const searchresults = res.data;

        this.setState({ searchresults });
      });
  };

  onChangeSong = e => {
    this.setState({ song: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.song}
            onChange={this.onChangeSong}
          />
          <input value="search" type="submit" />
        </form>
        <div>{this.submitSearchResults()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class SearchResults extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.obj.text}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SearchComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I copied your code and it runs great. But when I remove the "Axios replacement" And try to fetch the api code I get the following error:

TypeError: this.state.searchresults.map is not a function

When I run console.log(this.state.searchresult) all data are objects. The original state of searchresult is set as [ ] .

Comment: @JeroendeBeer That's frustrating. Maybe the array you want to set in your state is named something else than `res.data`? E.g. `res.data.results` or something like that. Maybe you can `console.log` the `res` in the axios callback and see what it contains.

Comment: Yes, it is res.data.tracks.items (spotify api). Thank you, learned a lot.